Calculating Probability in Disjoint and Independent Events
We have three events, $A$, $B$, and $C$. $A$ and $B$ are independent. $A$ and $C$ are disjoint. $P(A) = 0.3$, $P(B) = 0.6$, $P(C) = 0.4$, $P(C^) = 0.8$. ($C'$) is the complement of $(C)$. Calculate $P(B \cap A' \cap C')$.
Solution
We begin by rewriting the probability as a conditional probability with respect to $B$:
$P(B \cap A' \cap C) = P(A' \cap C' | B) \cdot P(B)$.
Furthermore, we want to use that $A \cap C = \emptyset$. The complement of the event $A' \cap C'$ is $A \cup C$, and $A$ and $C$ being disjoint implies that $P(A' \cap C') = 1 - (P(A) + P(C))$.
This also holds when conditioned on $B$, and we have:
$P(A' \cap C' | B) = 1 - P(A | B) - P(C | B) = 1 - P(A) + (1 - P(C' | B))$,
where we also used that $A$ and $B$ are independent. Substituting the given probabilities, we get:
$P(B \cap A' \cap C') = (1 - P(A) - (1 - P(C' | B))) \cdot P(B)$
$= (1 - 0.3 - 0.2) \cdot 0.6$
$= 0.300$.
My question
The part I don't understand is how:
$$P(A' \cap C' | B) = 1 - P(A | B) - P(C | B)$$
Shouldn't it be something like:
I had drawn a picture of it and the possibility of not A and not C given B is the blue, green and yellow area. The sample space is B so it follows:
$P(A' \cap C' | B) = P(A' \cap C')/ P(B)$


There's a typo in your specification of the problem, part of which currently says $\ P(C)=0.4,P(C^)=0.8\ .$ The given solution would make sense if this was meant to be $\ P(C)=0.4,P(C'|B)=0.8\ ,$ but it's not really obvious that that's what it was intended to be.

No, it's not true that $\ P(A'\cap C'\,|\,B)=\frac{P(A'\cap\,C')}{P(B)}\ .$ By definition
$$
P(A'\cap C'\,|B)=\frac{P((A'\cap C')\color{red}{\cap B})}{P(B)}\ ,\tag{1}\label{e1}
$$
and since
\begin{align}
(A'\cap C')\cap B&=B\setminus(B\cap(A\cup C)\\
&=B\setminus\big((B\cap A)\cup(B\cap C)\big)\ ,\tag{2}\label{e2}
\end{align}
$\ B\cap A\ $ and $\ B\cap C\ $ are disjoint, and $\ (B\cap A)\cup(B\cap C)\subseteq B\ $ then
$$
P((A'\cap C')\cap B)=P(B)-\big(P(A\cap B)+P(C\cap B)\big)\tag{3}\label{e3}\ .
$$
From equations (\ref{e1}), (\ref{e2}) and (\ref{e3}) we have
\begin{align}
P(A'\cap C'\,|\,B)&=\frac{P(B)-P(A\cap B)-P(C\cap B)}{P(B)}\\
&=1-\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}-\frac{P(C\cap B)}{P(B)}\\
&=1-P(A\,|\,B)-P(C\,|\,B)\ ,
\end{align}
where the final equation again follows from the definition of conditional probability.
